# Reading XML using Python minidom and iterating over each node

Tags: python, xml, parsing, minidom

I have an XML structure that looks like the following, but on a much larger scale:

```
<root>
    <conference name='1'>
        <author>
            Bob
        </author>
        <author>
            Nigel
        </author>
    </conference>
    <conference name='2'>
        <author>
            Alice
        </author>
        <author>
            Mary
        </author>
    </conference>
</root>
```

For this, I used the following code:

```
dom = parse(filepath)
conference=dom.getElementsByTagName('conference')
for node in conference:
    conf_name=node.getAttribute('name')
    print conf_name
    alist=node.getElementsByTagName('author')
    for a in alist:
        authortext= a.nodeValue
        print authortext
```

However, the authortext that is printed out is 'None.' I tried messing around with using variations like what is below, but it causes my program to break.

```
authortext=a[0].nodeValue
```

The correct output should be:

```
1
Bob
Nigel
2
Alice
Mary
```

But what I get is:

```
1
None
None
2
None
None
```

Any suggestions on how to tackle this problem?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

your `authortext` is of type 1 (`ELEMENT_NODE`), normally you need to have `TEXT_NODE` to get a string. This will work

```
a.childNodes[0].nodeValue
```

Answer (score 6):

Element nodes don't have a nodeValue. You have to look at the Text nodes inside them. If you know there's always one text node inside you can say `element.firstChild.data` (data is the same as nodeValue for text nodes).

Be careful: if there is no text content there will be no child Text nodes and `element.firstChild` will be null, causing the `.data` access to fail.

Quick way to get the content of direct child text nodes:

```
text= ''.join(child.data for child in element.childNodes if child.nodeType==child.TEXT_NODE)
```

In DOM Level 3 Core you get the `textContent` property you can use to get text from inside an Element recursively, but minidom doesn't support this (some other Python DOM implementations do).

Answer (score 2):

Quick access:

```
node.getElementsByTagName('author')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you always have one text data value per author you can use element.firstChild.data

```
dom = parseString(document)
conferences = dom.getElementsByTagName("conference")

# Each conference here is a node
for conference in conferences:
    conference_name = conference.getAttribute("name")
    print 
    print conference_name.upper() + " - "

    authors = conference.getElementsByTagName("author")
    for author in authors:
        print "  ", author.firstChild.data
    # for

    print
```

Answer (score 0):

I played around with it a bit, and here's what I got to work:

```
# ...
authortext= a.childNodes[0].nodeValue
print authortext
```

leading to output of:

```
C:\temp\py>xml2.py
1
Bob
Nigel
2
Alice
Mary
```

I can't tell you exactly why you have to access the childNode to get the inner text, but at least that's what you were looking for.