# XML parsing in python using Elelment tree package

Tags: python, xml, parsing

Actuvally am having below XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"> 
        <soapenv:Body> 
                <c:RetriveByVehicleLineModelYearResponse xmlns:a="urn:ford/VehicleOrder/LegacyFeatureMapping/v2.0" xmlns:b="urn:ford/VehicleOrder/SingleOrderEdit/v1.0" xmlns:c="urn:ford/interface/VehicleOrder/LegacyFeatureMapping/v2"> 
                        <c:PortInstalledOptionFeature> 
                                <a:VehicleLineId>13001</a:VehicleLineId> 
                                <a:ModelYear>2014</a:ModelYear> 
                                <a:LegacyColumn>12</a:LegacyColumn> 
                                <a:LegacyValue>178       </a:LegacyValue> 
                                <a:SalesCode>W78</a:SalesCode> 
                                <a:MappingId>41859</a:MappingId> 
                                <a:MappingSeq>0</a:MappingSeq> 
                                <a:MappingDirection>B</a:MappingDirection> 
                                <a:TargetFeature> 
                                        <a:TargetCatgegory> 
                                                <a:Id>181</a:Id> 
                                                <a:Name>LIGHT TRUCK WHEELBASES        </a:Name> 
                                                <a:Type>P</a:Type> 
                                                <a:FamilyCode>AA5</a:FamilyCode> 
                                        </a:TargetCatgegory> 
                                        <a:OrderFeatureId>15615</a:OrderFeatureId> 
                                        <a:WersCode>AA5K8</a:WersCode> 
                                        <a:OrderFeatureName>178 /4521MM WHEELBASE         </a:OrderFeatureName> 
                                        <a:PIO>false</a:PIO> 
                                        <a:SummaryFeature>false</a:SummaryFeature> 
                                </a:TargetFeature> 
                                <a:TargetFeature> 
                                        <a:TargetCatgegory> 
                                                <a:Id>181</a:Id> 
                                                <a:Name>LIGHT TRUCK WHEELBASES        </a:Name> 
                                                <a:Type>P</a:Type> 
                                                <a:FamilyCode>AA5</a:FamilyCode> 
                                        </a:TargetCatgegory> 
                                        <a:OrderFeatureId>15615</a:OrderFeatureId> 
                                        <a:WersCode>AA5K8_second time</a:WersCode> 
                                        <a:OrderFeatureName>178 /4521MM WHEELBASE         </a:OrderFeatureName> 
                                        <a:PIO>false</a:PIO> 
                                        <a:SummaryFeature>false</a:SummaryFeature> 
                                </a:TargetFeature> 
                        </c:PortInstalledOptionFeature> 
                        <c:PortInstalledOptionFeature> 
                                <a:VehicleLineId>13001</a:VehicleLineId> 
                                <a:ModelYear>2014</a:ModelYear> 
                                <a:LegacyColumn>12</a:LegacyColumn> 
                                <a:LegacyValue>190       </a:LegacyValue> 
                                <a:SalesCode>W90</a:SalesCode> 
                                <a:MappingId>41860</a:MappingId> 
                                <a:MappingSeq>0</a:MappingSeq> 
                                <a:MappingDirection>B</a:MappingDirection> 
                                <a:TargetFeature> 
                                        <a:TargetCatgegory> 
                                                <a:Id>181</a:Id> 
                                                <a:Name>LIGHT TRUCK WHEELBASES        </a:Name> 
                                                <a:Type>P</a:Type> 
                                                <a:FamilyCode>AA5</a:FamilyCode> 
                                        </a:TargetCatgegory> 
                                        <a:OrderFeatureId>15616</a:OrderFeatureId> 
                                        <a:WersCode>AA5MA</a:WersCode> 
                                        <a:OrderFeatureName>190 /4826MM WHEELBASE         </a:OrderFeatureName> 
                                        <a:PIO>false</a:PIO> 
                                        <a:SummaryFeature>false</a:SummaryFeature> 
                                </a:TargetFeature> 
                        </c:PortInstalledOptionFeature> 
                </c:RetriveByVehicleLineModelYearResponse> 
        </soapenv:Body> 
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

============================

My expected Output is:

```
WersCode 
AA5K8 
AA5MA
```

============== For this I have used below Code:

```
import glob   
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET 

Fatfile = open('#Var_SOE_VLIS_Response_Output\\Sales_to_Wers_Code2.txt', 'a') 
try: 
   tree = ET.parse('#Var_ENG_Response_Files\\SoapResponse1.xml')     
   Fatfile.write('1111') 
   WersCodeList = tree.findall('./{urn:ford/VehicleOrder/LegacyFeatureMapping/v2.0}PortInstalledOptionFeature') 
   Fatfile.write('\n2222') 
  # x = len(WersCodeList) 
  # Fatfile.write(x) 
   Fatfile.write('\n333') 
   for WersCode in WersCodeList : 
         Fatfile.write('\n444') 
         WersCode = WersCode.find('.//{urn:ford/VehicleOrder/LegacyFeatureMapping/v2.0}WersCode') 
         Fatfile.write('\n') 
         Fatfile.write(WersCode.text) 
except : 
    Fatfile.write(' \nsorry') 
Fatfile.write(' \nSuccess')
```

====

But I could not able to get the WersCode List using Findall.

Please please please help on this .. am struggling sice one week sir...

Comment: Take a look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1412004/reading-xml-using-python-minidom-and-iterating-over-each-node

Answer (score 0):

Try using `lxml`. It is simpler and faster than `ElementTree`.

Answer (score 0):

Stop stuggling and read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14853417/3991164) to another question. Finding it is straightforward using search terms "element tree python findall namespace xml", but when your suspect is not namespace handling, you can easily get lost.

Using proper namespace handling, the code also becomes very simple and clear:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
namespaces = {
    "a" : "urn:ford/VehicleOrder/LegacyFeatureMapping/v2.0",
    "b" : "urn:ford/VehicleOrder/SingleOrderEdit/v1.0",
    "c" : "urn:ford/interface/VehicleOrder/LegacyFeatureMapping/v2"
}
tree = ET.parse('wers.xml')
#print("input file found")
piof_list = tree.findall('.//c:PortInstalledOptionFeature', namespaces)
#print("{0:d} PIOFs found".format(len(piof_list)))
for piof in piof_list:
    #print(piof)
    wers_code = piof.find('.//a:WersCode', namespaces)
    print(wers_code.text)
```